# Ubuntu Starts to a black screen with UFW error

Tags: boot, uefi, hp, ufw

I have Ubuntu 20.04(I believe) installed on an old HP Compaq 8200 that I use for projects and whatnot and I've had an issue of it not booting properly. When I turn it on, it does the HP boot, an error message repeated about a dozen times about the TPM chip not being enabled, one final message about UFW not being enabled, and then it goes to the Ubuntu splash and then black. I was able to get into GRUB but not much help in there. I also tried turning off UEFI and booting into legacy with the same issue. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I enabled the embedded device security and the tpm error went away during boot but it still has the UFW error and goes to a black screen

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1488492/edit) your question and add more details about your system?  HP doesn't make Optiplex, but Dell does.  Also, there could be an issue with video drivers as to why it is not booting properly.  You may also be able to get into a TTY session by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F# (probably 3-7) so that you can log in to get logs, etc.

Comment: Absolute bone head I am lol updated to the Compaq 8200. Not sure what video card but it's an i5-2500S and from 2011 so probably a basic intel video card

Comment: HP 8200s came with a number of video cards; so you'll need to be specific as to which you purchased, or if it was changed since originally purchased. The make/model with 5+ variations and CPU chosen is no indication of what GPU choice was made at purchase time; esp. given 'black' screen relates to GPU.  Being specific with details like release are also helpful; eg. 20.04 is an old release thus kernel stack choices haven't occurred in a *long* time, where as if it was 22.04 then that's somewhat recent (*thus kernel module or 'driver' change may have occurred*)

Comment: Sorry for the delay on this and appreciate y'all's help. I made a USB installation and booted into that but it's showing the llvmpipe instead of the graphics card probably because I'm booting from the USB. Any help on what I can do now that I have access to my drives though?